# javascript Object.create()

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
function Shape() {}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); 
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle);// true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape);// true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

I have come across this example from MDN. 
May I know if there is a significant change to replace `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);` with `Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;` ?
The outcomes are the same in both cases.
I have been told that prototype property is an object itself, so why do we use object.create() to create another object first and then assign it to rectangle's property? why no directly assign shape's prototype to rectangle's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand your example in order to see the difference.

```
function Shape() {}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); 
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

Rectangle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  console.info('Rectangle moved.');
};

var shape = new Shape();
var rect = new Rectangle();
console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle);// true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape);// true
shape.move(1, 1); // 'Shape moved.'
rect.move(1, 1); // 'Rectangle moved.'
```

And now let's see what happens when you don't use `Object.create()`:

```
function Shape() {}

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); 
}

Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;

Rectangle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  console.info('Rectangle moved.');
};

var shape = new Shape();
var rect = new Rectangle();
console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle);// true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape);// true
shape.move(1, 1); // 'Rectangle moved.'
rect.move(1, 1); // 'Rectangle moved.'
```

When you don't use `Object.create()` to create a new prototype based on the `Shape.prototype` object, you are simply assigning a reference to the existing prototype and later on when you override some of `Rectangle`'s prototype methods, you are actually overriding the `Shape`'s prototype method as well, as it's the same object.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

`Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;`

both *Rectangle* and *Shape* prototype will be the same object and every method/property you add to *Rectangle* would be present in *Shape* too.

Answer (score 0):

This approach `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);` will ensure that `Shape.prototype` is inherited by `Rectangle` in terms of it's(`Shape.prototype`) base functionality. This prevents `Shape.prototype` modification by `Rectangle.prototype`.
Consider the following:

```
...
Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype; // Shape.prototype is assigned as reference
var rect = new Rectangle();

Rectangle.prototype.add = "add method";
console.log(JSON.stringify(Shape.prototype,0,4));
...
// the output will be like(Shape.prototype was changed):
{
    "add": "add method"
}
```

As you can see, assigning `Shape.prototype` directly to `Rectangle.prototype` as reference allows `Rectangle.prototype` to modify `Shape.prototype`.
Whereas `Object.create(Shape.prototype)` will be assigned as new "independent" object (All `Rectangle.prototype` extensions won't effect `Shape.prototype`)